# how to load a webview while another webview is loading?

Tags: android, android-webview

1. here i want load a web view while loading another webview 
   my code is
2. actually my theme i have two option here one is google and facebbok,while opening the application google will be loaded , if we press fb button facebook will be loaded but that will time taken process
3. To avoiding that time i want to load fb in progress of google only (while loading google only we have to load fb in second web view it is in hide state)
   4.when user go for fb we have to show that without time taken.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   Button google,fb;

   RelativeLayout paremt;


   @Override

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


   // adding webview before loading the ui design

   getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);


   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   final WebView wv=new WebView(MainActivity.this);
   final WebView wv1=new WebView(MainActivity.this);

   wv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   wv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   wv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



   paremt=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel2);
    paremt.addView(wv);
   //paremt.addView(wv1);

   final Activity activity = this;
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
      public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
        // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
          System.out.println(" progress is  "+progress);

          //loading hidden webview with second link, while completion of second link

          if(progress==100)
          {
              wv1.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
          }

        activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
      }
    });
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });

   wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");

   google=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   fb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
   int j=paremt.getChildCount();
   System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa   "+j);
   google.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           paremt.removeAllViews();
           paremt.addView(wv);
           wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

       }
   });
   fb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           paremt.removeAllViews();
           wv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           paremt.addView(wv1);
           wv1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                  public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                    // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                    // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                    activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
                  }
                });
                wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                });

               //wv1.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
       }
   });
   ```

   }
   }

Comment: if i use more than two webviews how i can load them

Answer (score 0):

```
wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
wv1.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
```

Call these lines simultaneously and remove call of facebook url from onProgressChanged method